# Updating multiple Windows server everytime code is pushed into Github

Tags: deployment, github, windows-server-2008

We run 8 EC2 instances behind a load balancer currently (used to run 2 - but our app took off and we have more traffic now)

Our code is deployed on Github.

When we had 2 servers, we easily remote desktop-ed into them and did a git pull.
But that seems insane now considering we have 8 servers and might have more in the future.

This is for an Asp.Net webservice (built over MVC3) deployed on IIS on a Windows 2008 server.

I wanted to know what are the best practices to handle this?
I would ideally love it if I could push to a branch / or a completely new production only repo (if needed) and all the servers get notified and pull the changes.

Worst case, I am thinking of writing a notifier service which does this on each server - but before I dive in and spend time on it, was wondering if there is something available out of the box which would help me get there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http://octopusdeploy.com/ ?

Comment: No. I haven't. I'll give it a go. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

check webhook
https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks.
you can write a simple http handler to let github push notification to you.
then you can do whatever you wanna do .